# POST alamofire array parameter

Tags: android, swift, alamofire

How do I convert this android code below

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
       mParams.put("items[" + i + "][id]", items.get(i).getType().getId());
       mParams.put("items["+i+"][note]", items.get(i).getNote());
   }
```

to swift for alamofire.

the following is my code but it's not working:

```
for var i = 0; i < self.survey.items.count; i++ {
            parameters["items[\(self.survey.items[i].type?.id)]"] = [
                "[id]": self.survey.items[i].id,
                "[note]": self.survey.items[i].note

                ]

            print(self.survey.items[i].id)
        }
```

--

The `parameters` looks like:

```
parameter: [
    "items[0][id]": 3, 
    "items[1][note]": Pen, 
    "lat": 3.070235299720939, 
    "status_id": 1, 
    "items[3][id]": 3, 
    "name": Bih, 
    "lng": 101.6110375110495, 
    "items[2][id]": 4, 
    "items[0][note]": Keychain, 
    "items[3][note]": Keychain, 
    "is_avocated": 1, 
    "items[2][note]": Pen, 
    "items[1][id]": 4
]
```

I managed to add only 1 with

```
parameters["items"] = [[
            "id": 4,
            "note": "Pen"

        ]]
```

but once i made it

```
parameters["items[0]"] = [[
            "id": 4,
            "note": "Pen"

        ]]
```

It doesn't add :( Again no errors

Latest Edit: Server side(Laravel) is expecting

```
$items = Input::get('items', []);
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        //$survey->items()->attach($item['id'], ['note' => $item['note']]);
        $sItem = new SurveyItem;
        $sItem->survey_id = $survey->id;
        $sItem->item_id = $item['id'];
        $sItem->note = $item['note'];
        $sItem->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $sItem->save();
    }
```

Comment: may be directly `parameters["items[\(self.survey.items[i].type?.id)][id]"] = self.survey.items[i].id`?

Comment: I've tried that but it's not working :(

Comment: (a) define "not working"; (b) show us what `parameters` ended up looking like when you did this.

Comment: parameter: 
["items[0][id]": 3, "items[1][note]": Pen, "lat": 3.070235299720939, "status_id": 1, "items[3][id]": 3, "name": Bih, "lng": 101.6110375110495, "items[2][id]": 4, "items[0][note]": Keychain, "items[3][note]": Keychain, "is_avocated": 1, "items[2][note]": Pen, "items[1][id]": 4]

The server didn't return error, just didn't add the items into the database
And just for the record, I am able to add to the database in cocoarestclient with items[0][id] = something and items[0][note] = something

Comment: Your index is wrong. Note, in your Android version, you're using `i`, but in your Swift rendition, you're using the `survey.items[i].type?.id`. Use `i`.

Comment: I've used your code(you used i), same result :/, i use survey id is just to test around all possibilities. This is my first time plugging in an array to alamofire

Comment: Well, I tested it on my server, and it's being received fine. Again, what precisely do you mean by "it's not working"? Is your code crashing? Is the request being received successfully but some data is missing? The server is returning some error (and if so, precisely what error is it reporting)?

Comment: The server didn't return error, just didn't add the items into the database And just for the record, I am able to add to the database in cocoarestclient with items[0][id] = something and items[0][note] = something

No crashes too

does alamofire interpret my array the same way?

Comment: Alamofire doesn't interpret it at all. If `parameters` has an entry whose key is `items[0][id]`, then that's what it sends (and is correctly interpreted by server). In terms of why the server is not saving it, it could be many things. I'd suggest changing the server to do more validation of the input and return meaningful more errors/responses to facilitate diagnosis. If not, I'd suggest using [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) to watch the iOS request and compare it against the Android request, and see how they differ. There's something else going on (missing header, POST vs GET, etc.).

Comment: But I can add that with Cocoarestclient though

Comment: Yeah, it worked on my server, too. That tells us that the problem isn't the Swift code, and that there's something else going on, right? Perhaps edit your question and show us how you're submitting the request and how you're doing your error handling. And I frequently find Charles very useful in diagnosing network problems. Are you seeing the request and the response there?

Answer (score 1):

The Swift equivalent to your Android code would be:

```
var parameters = [String:String]()

for var i = 0; i < survey.items.count; i++ {
    parameters["items[\(i)][id]"] = survey.items[i].id
    parameters["items[\(i)][note]"] = survey.items[i].note
}
```

Or, you can also do:

```
var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
for var i = 0; i < survey.items.count; i++ {
    parameters["items[\(i)]"] = ["id" : survey.items[i].id, "note" : survey.items[i].note]
}
```

When you submit the request, make sure you check for errors, e.g.:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch (response.result) {
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("error: \(error)")
        case .Success(let responseObject):
            print("responseObject: \(responseObject)")
        }
}
```

--

You say that the following works:

```
parameters["items"] = [[ "id": 4, "note": "Pen" ]]
```

That generates a body that looks like:

```
items%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=4&items%5B%5D%5Bnote%5D=Pen
```

Which, when the percent escapes are removed, looks like:

```
items[][id]=4&items[][note]=Pen
```

Whereas my above examples generate:

```
items%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=4&items%5B0%5D%5Bnote%5D=Pen
```

I.e.:

```
items[0][id]=4&items[0][note]=Pen
```

As I interpret your Android code, the latter should be the correct format. I cannot reconcile your Android code with the results of your tests.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't get through :( I can do that on cocoarestclient though :(
I'm using Alamofire 3.0 if it matters

Comment: That's curious, because it seems like these are both ways to construct request similar to your android request. Without seeing the raw android request (such as observed in Charles) or without seeing the server code, I cannot help you further.

Comment: But do you at least have any idea why this worked? 
parameters["items"] = [[
            "id": 4,
            "note": "Pen"

        ]]

Comment: I've also added server side get()

Comment: and the reason I'm sure it's my problem cause android and cocoarestclient is fine, hence I kept asking :( Sorry if I failed to say my problem correctly cause I myself am equally confused

Comment: I cannot reconcile your empirical results with your Android code sample, which you say works fine. That's why I was suggesting looking at the Charles output of the operational Android code. Once we see what a good request in Android results in, we can reproduce that in iOS.